# iOS13 app generated from Xcode 11.3 is crashing while launching if I download and install from testflight.In simulator app is working fine

Tags: ios13, xcode11.3

The iOS app is working fine when we download and install from testflight if I generate that app from Xcode 9.1 and MacOS 10.13.6(High Sierra)and uploaded to testflight.I have opened the same code from Xcode 11.3 on latest MacOS Catalina and generated iPA and uploaded to the testflight using proper distribution certificate. I was able to download and install app but app is crashing during app launch.

Please suggest me what could be the reason for this issue. I am adding some app crash logs from my iPhone.

```
{"app_name":"XXXX","app_cohort":"2|date=1586433600000&sf=143467&tid=e7af489f4214d36d52f2f775602345e93b2fd4cfcc690cd6ff09b0e7262ffdd7&ttype=i","app_version":"1.2.5","timestamp":"2020-04-09 17:59:31.50 +0530","slice_uuid":"45d30e88-5b71-32e7-854b-dcc2a43f5d99","adam_id":586832868,"build_version":"424","bundleID":"com.YYYY.XXXX","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.3.1 (17D50)","incident_id":"C379DDCD-83EA-49AC-A4B5-24E0316D0681","is_beta":true,"name":"XXXX"}
Incident Identifier: C379DDCD-83EA-49AC-A4B5-24E0316D0681
Beta Identifier:     5438D6EC-9706-4D7C-9DED-0259D2ECBE6A
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,8
Process:             XXXX [51890]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E8C2C24C-087A-49B9-B78E-E6BC18A44EC2/XXXX.app/XXXX
Identifier:          com.YYYY.XXXX
Version:             424 (1.2.5)
AppStoreTools:       11E146
AppVariant:          1:iPhone11,8:13
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.YYYY.XXXX [4881]


Date/Time:           2020-04-09 17:59:30.6770 +0530
Launch Time:         2020-04-09 17:59:30.4400 +0530
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.3.1 (17D50)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    2.04.03
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x8039c2a100000002 -> 0x0000002100000002 (possible pointer authentication failure)
VM Region Info: 0x2100000002 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 130459631619  
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_NANO            0000000280000000-00000002a0000000 [512.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--->  
      UNUSED SPACE AT END

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [51890]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00000001a6012798 0x1a600d000 + 22424
1   XXXX                        0x00000001021e20d4 0x1020d4000 + 1106132
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a602d3f8 0x1a601f000 + 58360
3   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a6110168 0x1a6100000 + 65896
4   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a61027e8 0x1a6100000 + 10216
5   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a610fbf4 0x1a6100000 + 64500
6   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a612aee4 0x1a6100000 + 175844
7   dyld                            0x00000001024a4530 0x10249c000 + 34096
8   dyld                            0x00000001024a298c 0x10249c000 + 27020
9   dyld                            0x000000010249d22c 0x10249c000 + 4652
10  dyld                            0x000000010249d038 0x10249c000 + 4152

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x8039c2a100000002   x1: 0x00000001022dab37   x2: 0x000000000000000a   x3: 0xfffffffffffffffc
    x4: 0x0000000000000052   x5: 0x0000000000000056   x6: 0x00000001e6b53848   x7: 0x00000000000004d0
    x8: 0x000000028189c0c4   x9: 0x0000000000010000  x10: 0x0000000000000194  x11: 0x0000000000000001
   x12: 0x0000000000000003  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x00000000fffffffc  x15: 0x0000000000000018
   x16: 0x00000001a6012790  x17: 0x00000001eca7b3b0  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000001022dab37
   x20: 0x00000001022d7cd5  x21: 0x00000001022dab40  x22: 0x8039c2a100000002  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x000000000000017f  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000102329620  x27: 0x00000001022eb593
   x28: 0x00000001ef76d4d8   fp: 0x000000016dd290f0   lr: 0x00000001021e20d4
    sp: 0x000000016dd29090   pc: 0x00000001a6012798 cpsr: 0x00000000
   esr: 0x92000004 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault

Binary Images:
0x1020d4000 - 0x102307fff XXXX arm64  <45d30e885b7132e7854bdcc2a43f5d99> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/E8C2C24C-087A-49B9-B78E-E6BC18A44EC2/XXXX.app/XXXX
0x10249c000 - 0x102503fff dyld arm64e  <e008b93875933f57b94a747bc6c3beb5> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1a5ee4000 - 0x1a5efafff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64e  <1177e8a367aa3c8cb5605bcc40419d54> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x1a5efb000 - 0x1a5f2efff libxpc.dylib arm64e  <e2894301267b3872a3cd0aaf659353a9> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x1a5f2f000 - 0x1a5f2ffff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64e  <0fb3b7d281de30979e83b408b48e8b0e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x1a5f30000 - 0x1a5faefff libsystem_c.dylib arm64e  <8b9c0d18aeba3e24a95f2ec54f9fb4ef> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1a5faf000 - 0x1a5febfff libdispatch.dylib arm64e  <0c7a69cdf2ee3426bfd8742c903d3d07> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1a5fec000 - 0x1a600cfff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64e  <479f1b0225ee32ce8c0afaf20cd9e0c6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x1a600d000 - 0x1a6013fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64e  <b07cc9f89c9f38b0bb974a77bf6a5db4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x1a6014000 - 0x1a601efff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <637416f6a7a3339b96ed9ebc80d38988> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x1a601f000 - 0x1a604ffff libobjc.A.dylib arm64e  <2c18c54e6c84310c851ff9602890d908> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1a6050000 - 0x1a60bcfff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64e  <9d52b5f81c483635ad32214f878e3e29> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x1a60bd000 - 0x1a60d0fff libc++abi.dylib arm64e  <b60e71f7dd75323c8831b1ca4d42e3cb> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1a60d1000 - 0x1a60fffff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <ae36dce0999d39909eed01106f17dc90> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x1a6100000 - 0x1a6133fff libdyld.dylib arm64e  <9d12204719b736a2a89227401f9e0e6c> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x1a6134000 - 0x1a613cfff libsystem_darwin.dylib arm64e  <e2c1c480b2ec3bbea3fa4c70e4056c64> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
0x1a613d000 - 0x1a6197fff libc++.1.dylib arm64e  <fff3d40d85a0308eac32908bca1188d0> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x1a6198000 - 0x1a61d9fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64e  <c2e15922d993340aaa5da454a57dfb76> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x1a61da000 - 0x1a6557fff CoreFoundation arm64e  <dc2c95c6b95439e886a25e0af8801e87> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x1a6558000 - 0x1a65befff SystemConfiguration arm64e  <9e1b636801ac32da9dabce33f20ce872> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x1a65bf000 - 0x1a688afff Foundation arm64e  <7a7a96af79e43db1890442e61cae8999> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1a688b000 - 0x1a68bdfff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64e  <15ee962961303d46964ecd419e64345a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x1a68be000 - 0x1a6a41fff CoreServices arm64e  <9298be2d0bd93660bddcf43d32ea3872> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/CoreServices
0x1a6a42000 - 0x1a6aa4fff libSparse.dylib arm64e  <797932fbc17f372bbd2cb9bc2d55cac1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparse.dylib
0x1a6aa5000 - 0x1a6f9efff ImageIO arm64e  <b301e385830f311ebce0e786df524e8e> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x1a6f9f000 - 0x1a6fa1fff ConstantClasses arm64e  <96b656dd09a03e82b9c2917ab36a3fdd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
```

Comment: Does "XXXX" in the stack trace refer to a symbol in your code? Have you tried symbolicating the crash log to get at the corresponing line number?

Comment: Thanks @Gereon. I have just replaced my actual app name with "XXXX"  to avoid displaying it to all before posting here. I am trying to symbolicate crash logs now .

Comment: When I symbolicate the crash logs, It is showing the following statement.
-[AppDelegate managedObjectContext] in AppDelegate.m file. and the exact statement is:  return _managedObjectContext;

Comment: You will have to find a way to reproduce the crash locally. Have you tried compiling in release mode when running on your test device?

Comment: I have to connect to mac remotely, so not possible to run from xcode onto device by connecting to mac. As of now checking by creating ipa and installing on my device locally.

Comment: When I test app from xcode 11.1 onto device which has iOS 13.3, I am getting crash when app launches and if I test on device which has iOS 9.3, it is working fine.
I have got the following log in xcode console: 
objc[1800]: Class RKResponse is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ResponseKit.framework/ResponseKit (0x1fb221b08) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/83419794-B39A-4718-B32B-C0169AA837EE/AppName.app/AppName (0x103012870). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this crash by renaming RKResponse class name of Restkit framework by adding some prefix to it. So that it will not conflict with RKResponseKit framework class RKResponse